# Duplicate content and pagination

Tags: php, pagination, seo

I have an archive page that displays the number of articles published. Because there were so many, I ran a pagination script:

for `127.0.0.1/archive/2/?p=x&pp=y`

where p is the page number and pp is number of articles to display per page

The pagination looks like this

```
Prev  1  2  3  4 ... 12   NEXT
```

with each item linking to p `<a href="?p=x">x</a>`

I also have the items per page setter: 25 | 50 | 100 `(<a href="?pp=y">y</a>)`

Now I have a PHP script that fixes pp into a session variable. But I am worried about duplicate content (since incrementing pp values will be inclusive) and also content not getting indexed because its not in the pagination link. so in the example above, pages 5-11 will not be indexed.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Is this a question in regards to SEO? It might be nice to explicitly state that; I just spent a few minutes staring at this question wondering what "duplicate content" and "content not getting indexed" signified from a technical point of view. If it is about SEO, I recommend asking this at [Webmasters Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). It's a very nice Stack Exchange site with competent people and they usually give great answers. :)

Comment: Speaking of Webmasters Stack Exchange, check out [_Pagination, Duplicate Content, and SEO_](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7136/pagination-duplicate-content-and-seo) on said site.

Comment: [Same question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/68370/17633) on [webmasters.se].